# homology of mapping telescope of a monoid

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid with multiplication $\cdot$, $\pi_0(M)=\mathbb{N}$, and $m\in M$ in the component $1\in \mathbb{N}$ . We form a mapping telescope
$$
M\overset{ {\cdot m}}\longrightarrow M\overset{ {\cdot m}}\longrightarrow M\overset{ {\cdot m}}\longrightarrow \cdots
$$
We denote the space of this mapping telescope by $M_\infty$.
The sequence of the above mapping telescope induces a sequence of homomorphisms of Pontrjagin rings on homology 
$$
H_*(M)\overset{ {(\cdot m)_*}}\longrightarrow H_*(M)\overset{ {(\cdot m)_*}}\longrightarrow H_*(M)\overset{ {(\cdot m)_*}}\longrightarrow \cdots
$$
 By [Homology of mapping telescope](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847354/homology-of-mapping-telescope), the direct limit of the above sequence on homology is $H_*(M_\infty)$.

In the paper [Homology fibrations and group completion theorem](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf), by McDuff-Segal, page 281, line 13-14: If $H_*(M)[\pi_0(M)^{-1}]$ can be formed by "right fractions" (cf. page 279, bottom line 4-7, [Homology fibrations and group completion theorem](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf))  then the direct limit of the above sequence on homology is precisely $H_*(M)[\pi_0(M)^{-1}]$.

My question: (1). how to use "right fractions" to prove that the direct limit of the above sequence on homology is precisely $H_*(M)[\pi_0(M)^{-1}]$?

(2). given a specific topological monoid $M$, is there a direct way to check whether $M$ satisfies the condition: $H_*(M)[\pi_0(M)^{-1}]$ can be formed by "right fractions"?

Comment: You need more assumptions on $M$ and $m$. Consider e.g. $m$ being the neutral element.

Comment: Concerning your edit: See my answer on your recent question. I recommend you to try to understand Hatcher's account on the group completion theorem in a special case first.