# when will homology and direct limit commute?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, monoid

**Question:**

Let a sequence of maps between topological spaces
$$
X_1\to^{f_1}X_2\to^{f_2}X_3\to^{f_3}\cdots
$$
The mapping telescope is denoted by $T$. Under what conditions will $H_*(T)$, the homology of $T$, will be the same as the direct limit of the following sequence
$$
H_*(X_1)\to^{f_1*}H_*(X_2)\to^{f_2*}H_*(X_3)\to^{f_3*}\cdots?
$$
Note that in particular,  if $f_1,f_2,......$ are injective, then $T=\bigcup X_i$ and by [Homology of mapping telescope](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847354/homology-of-mapping-telescope) or proposition 3.33 in Hatcher's book, homology and direct limit commute.

**Origin of the question:**

In the paper [Homology fibrations and group completion theorem, McDuff-Segal](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf,),
 the space $M_\infty$ is constructed as follows: Let $M$ be a topological monoid with $\pi_0M=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$, $M=\bigsqcup_{j=0}^\infty M_j$ where $M_j$'s are the path-connected components of $M$ such that $M_j$ is the component corresponding to $j\in\pi_0M$. We choose $m_1\in M_1$ and consider the sequence 
\begin{eqnarray}
M\overset{\cdot m_1} \longrightarrow M\overset{\cdot m_1} \longrightarrow M\overset{\cdot m_1} \longrightarrow \cdots
\end{eqnarray}
From this sequence we can form a mapping telescope
$$
M_\infty=(\bigsqcup_{i=1}^\infty [i-1,i]\times M)/\sim
$$
where $\sim$ is generated by the relations
$
(i,x)\sim (i, x m_1)
$
for any $x\in M$ and $i\geq 1$.
Assume that $H_*(M)[\pi_0M^{-1}]$ (which is just $H_*(M)[m_1^{-1}]$ in this case) can be constructed by right fractions. Then

**why $H_*(M_\infty)$ equals to the direct limit of 
\begin{eqnarray}
H_*(M)\overset{\cdot m_1*} \longrightarrow H_*(M)\overset{\cdot m_1*} \longrightarrow H_*(M)\overset{\cdot m_1*} \longrightarrow \cdots?
\end{eqnarray}**

Comment: Look at proposition 3.33 in Hatcher's book, for example: if every compact subset of $T$ is contained in some $X_n$, then $\varinjlim H_*(X_n) = H_*(\varinjlim X_n)$.

Comment: There seem to be two questions here: whether homology commutes with direct limits, and how the homology of the mapping telescope is related to the direct limit of the homology.

Comment: The second question has been answered in the context of topological spaces: [Homology of mapping telescope](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/847354/116766) I would hope that it isn't too different for topological monoids…